# jQuery UI drag and drop stop not firing as expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

```
$('#img' + imgID).draggable({ helper: 'clone', opacity: 0.35, stop: dragImageEnd() });

        // Called when a drag image has been dropped
        function dragImageEnd(){
            alert(currentlyOverFolderID);
        }
```

The drag event is working perfectly as expected, except when the draggable property is being added initially to each element it fires the dragImageEnd() event, and when I start dragging and dropping after that the event never fires.

I'm probably using it incorrectly, any tips?

Comment: Are the events being assigned on document ready, or at a later time?

Comment: The draggable assignment is being made within the document ready function yes.  The dragImageend is defined above that function.

Comment: Works perfectly when I define the function inside, but not when I link it to my own function, that's where the problem is.  I'm new to jquery so am probably doing it wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From

```
{ stop: dragImageEnd() }
```

to

```
{ stop: dragImageEnd }
```

Comment: Thanks!  Just getting used to syntax